# leaderboard example, confusion with 'selected_name' return value

Tags: javascript, meteor

In the leaderboard example, in leaderboard.html how come the call to {{selected_name}} returns the selected_name string but in the leaderboard.js file where the function is, it returns a boolean? I know this is more of a JS question but just trying to get my head wrapped around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of the following code?

```js
Template.leaderboard.selected_name = function () {
    var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));
    return player && player.name;
}
```

This does not return a boolean, although the `&&`-operator is a boolean operator. The "right way" would of course be to just have `return player.name`, but if `Players.find` returns `null` (no player with the selected id exists), this code would crash when executed. To avoid this from happening, the little hack with the `&&`-operator is used, which ensures that `player.name` is only executed if `player` is non falsye (not `null`). The result of the operator is the right hand side of it, so the name of the player is returned (or `null`, the left hand side of it, if it's `null`).